# Create group column based on the specific rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi guys I need your help on this one:

I need to populate an additional column (Directory) in sql server based on some specific rows. To do this I need to evaluate the column (Filename) and replicate it on the column (Directory) until the keyword changes. So the original table is like this:

[image]

And this is what I need to accomplish:

[image]

Can I use CTE? How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Always post sample data as text, instead of image

Comment: I agree with @Pரதீப் - And here's some additional reasoning why this is a good thing to do. ► [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `directory` naming format is consistent as your sample data then here is one way

```
SELECT id,Filename,
       Directory = Min(Filename)OVER(partition BY grp)
FROM   (SELECT *,
                grp= Sum(CASE WHEN Filename LIKE '-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                      OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)               
        FROM   Yourtable) a
```

Another method less dependent on naming convention

```
SELECT id,
       Filename,
       Directory = Max(iDirectory)OVER(partition BY grp)
FROM   (SELECT Id,
               Filename,
               grp,
               iDirectory=CASE WHEN Row_number() OVER(partition BY grp ORDER BY id) = 1 THEN Filename ELSE NULL END
        FROM   (SELECT *,
                       grp= Sum(CASE WHEN Filename LIKE '-%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                              OVER(ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
                FROM   #test) a)b
```

Comment: Thanks alot Pரதீப்!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare  @tt table (id int identity(1,1), [FileName] varchar(50), DirectoryName varchar(50))
insert into @tt([FileName]) values
('- Directory 1')
,('File a')
,('File b')
,('File c')
,('- Directory 2')
,('File d')
,('File e')
,('File f')
,('File g')

SELECT A.ID, A.[FILENAME],
    (
        SELECT TOP 1 [FILENAME] FROM @TT AS B 
        WHERE [FILENAME] LIKE '- DIRECTORY%'
        AND B.ID <= A.ID
        ORDER BY B.ID DESC
    ) AS DIRECTORYNAME
FROM @TT AS A
```